# Which of the wysiwyg modules will get in to the core of Drupal 8?

Tags: wysiwyg

I heard that there will be a wysiwyg editor in core for Drupal 8. Is there any decision made yet which one will make it?
I heard about:

- [CKEditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor)
- [Aloha Editor](http://drupal.org/project/aloha)
- [Wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg)

I have a decision to make which module I will add to my site and I need some deeper integration of the wysiwyg to the Drupal core. For example, that all external links are programmatically get stored in a link field an so on.
So I am hoping to get some of those features in feature when I choose the right module backported to Drupal /.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dries answered this in [From Aloha to Ckeditor](http://buytaert.net/from-aloha-to-ckeditor) on Jan 02, 2013:

> Therefore, we are going to switch from Aloha to CKEditor for Drupal 8
>   core. By making this switch, we will not only have a more mature
>   WYSIWYG editor, but we also free up resources to work on other parts
>   of Drupal's authoring experience. The CKEditor team has committed to
>   fix the 8 functional gaps that we've identified in their two next
>   upcoming releases.

Comment: Ok, that's clear, but does that mean that the base of the integration will be the module "CKEditor", thy still could use the Wysiwyg API module to do the integration or something new.

Comment: To add to your answer. ckeditor has already been committed to D8 and in the wysiwyg session at the recent Drupalcon it was mentioned that there will be nothing backported to D7 in this regards. At least from Drupal's side of things. The ckeditor team may add some of the features on their side, but nothing definitive.

Comment: @user5950 If you look at the Git history for the Drupal 8 core ckeditor module ... I believe all the committers are Core drupal contributors and not the D7 "ckeditor" module maintainers. See: http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/history/HEAD:/core/modules/ckeditor  I believe its a completely new module -- not intended to be backwards compatible (as is the rest of D8 <-> D7)